# Get user position in a fantasy league SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query which brings back total points for multiple events in a day.  Lets say 6.  The result of that query is

```
LeagueID    EntryID UserID  TotalPoints TotalBonusPoints    TotalPointsLastRace TotalBonusPointsLastRace    Position    PositionLastRace
3262          37     2        46              3                     39                      0                1               1
3262          46     4        46              3                     33                      3                2               4
3262          43     5        37              0                     35                      0                3               2
3262          40     6        33              3                     33                      3                4               3
3262          36     1        33              0                     21                      0                5               5
```

The query to run this is as below:

```
SELECT [LeagueID],
       [EntryID],
       [UserID],
       [TotalPoints],
       [TotalBonusPoints],
       [TotalPointsLastRace],
       [TotalBonusPointsLastRace],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [LeagueID] ORDER BY [TotalPoints] DESC, [TotalBonusPoints] DESC) AS [Position],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [LeagueID] ORDER BY [TotalPointsLastRace] DESC, [TotalBonusPointsLastRace] DESC) AS [PositionLastRace]
FROM
(

SELECT [League].[LeagueID],
        [Entry].[EntryID],
        [UserProfile].[UserID] AS [UserID],


        ---- get total points for a league for current position
        [dbo].[GetTotalPointsForLeague]([UserProfile].[UserID], [League].[LeagueID], 0, 0) AS [TotalPoints],

        -- get total points for a league for last race
        [dbo].[GetTotalPointsForLeague]([UserProfile].[UserID], [League].[LeagueID], 1, 0) AS [TotalPointsLastRace],

        -- get total BONUS points for a league for current position
        [dbo].[GetTotalPointsForLeague]([UserProfile].[UserID], [League].[LeagueID], 0, 1) AS [TotalBonusPoints],

        -- get total BONUS points for a league for last race
        [dbo].[GetTotalPointsForLeague]([UserProfile].[UserID], [League].[LeagueID], 1, 1) AS [TotalBonusPointsLastRace],

    FROM [Entry]
    INNER JOIN [League] ON [League].[LeagueID] = [Entry].[LeagueID]
    INNER JOIN [UserProfile] ON [UserProfile].[UserID] = [Entry].[UserID]
    WHERE [Entry].[LeagueID] IN

    (   SELECT DISTINCT [LeagueID] 
        FROM [Entry] 
        INNER JOIN [Meeting] ON [Entry].[MeetingID] = [Meeting].[MeetingID]
        WHERE [Entry].[UserID] = @UserID
        AND DATEDIFF(d ,CAST(@GetDate AS DATE),CAST([Meeting].[DateTime] AS DATE)) > -4 -- leagues newer than 1 days old
    )
    AND [Entry].[LeagueID] = 3262
) AS [DATA]

ORDER BY [LeagueID], [Position]
```

The issue I have is that you will see that the top two Entries in the league have the exact same Total Points AND Bonus Points.  If entrants have the same total points but different bonus points then the one with the most bonus points will be highest. You will see the bottom two entrants have equal total points but the higher bonus points is in the correct order.  My issue is the Position and PositionLastRace columns.  The positions should be:

```
1,1,2,3,3
```

I am using Position last race for calculating the movement of positions but I have no way to know how I can achieve this with the Row By, Does anyone see a quick solution to this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use Rank() instead of Row_Number()

Comment: @MartinSmith right you are - thanks for the correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT [LeagueID],
       [EntryID],
       [UserID],
       [TotalPoints],
       [TotalBonusPoints],
       [TotalPointsLastRace],
       [TotalBonusPointsLastRace],
       DENSE_RANK OVER( PARTITION BY [LeagueID] ORDER BY [TotalPoints] DESC, [TotalBonusPoints] DESC) AS [Position],
       DENSE_RANK OVER( PARTITION BY [LeagueID] ORDER BY [TotalPointsLastRace] DESC, [TotalBonusPointsLastRace] DESC) AS [PositionLastRace]
```

Comment: Excellent, I was not aware of this function.  RANK gave me 1,1,3,4,4 DENSE_RANK was the answer, thank you very much!